# What should be enqueued in Protractor ControlFlow explicitly?

Tags: protractor

As it is written in Protractor ControlFlow documentation - WebDriver async calls are automatically stored in Control Flow and will be executed in the defined order. In reality it seems that such approach is just a syntax sugar to avoid explicitly written "then" chains. But when I need to put my async function into Control Flow queue explicitly? Imagine that I have a pieced of code:

```
myAsync(xxx).then(function() {
   doSomething();
   return;
   });
```

and this code is in the middle of Protractor/Jasmine test so there are asserts above it and below; Should I do something like:

```
flow.execute(myAsync);
```

and if yes where I must put my "then" section in this case?

Answer (score 1):

```
it('blah', function() {
  browser.get('something');
  expect(element('foo').getText()).toBe('bar');

  var myAsync = function() {
    // if your async function doesn't return a promise, make it one
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer()
    // do some async stuff in here and then reject or fulfill with...
    if (error) {
      deferred.reject(error)
    else {
      deferred.fulfill(value);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  };

// hook into the controlFlow and execute the async thing so you can check after
browser.controlFlow().execute(myAsync);
expect(element('foo').getText()).toBe('baz');

// or check the return value of the promise
browser.controlFlow().execute(myAsync).then(function(result) {
  expect(result).toBe('something');
});
```